# data from read.csv and XLConnect in r give different results for simple regression

Tags: r

I have the same data file. I import into R by using read.csv and XLConnect package. Then I run simple regression between 2 numeric variable lm(N33 ~ N31, data = thi). Then I check for the homogeneity of variance with fligner.test. The results are different.

### The results from XLConnect:

## Simple regression:

`lmba <- lm(N33 ~ N31, data = thi)`

`summary(lmba)`

Call:

lm(formula = N33 ~ N31, data = thi)

Residuals:
Min 1Q Median 3Q Max

-9.6703 -2.6592 -0.3724 3.0324 16.1673

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept) -25.2481 1.4227 -17.75 <2e-16 ***

N31 5.2006 0.1153 45.10 <2e-16 ***

Residual standard error: 4.058 on 270 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.8828, Adjusted R-squared: 0.8824
F-statistic: 2034 on 1 and 270 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16

## Fligner test:

`fligner.test(N13 ~ N11, data = thi)`

Fligner-Killeen test of homogeneity of variances

data: N13 by N11

Fligner-Killeen:med chi-squared = 259.961, df = 245, p-value = 0.2443

### The results from read.csv:

## Simple regression:

`lmbt <- lm(N33 ~ N31, data = bt)`

`summary(lmbt)`

Call:

lm(formula = N33 ~ N31, data = bt)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max

-9.6497 -2.6758 -0.3566  3.0521 16.1764

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept) -25.2590     1.4226  -17.76   <2e-16 ***

N31           5.2013     0.1153   45.12   <2e-16 ***

Residual standard error: 4.057 on 270 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.8829,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.8825 
F-statistic:  2035 on 1 and 270 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

## Fligner test:

`fligner.test(N33 ~ N31, data = bt)`

```
    Fligner-Killeen test of homogeneity of variances
```

data:  N33 by N31

Fligner-Killeen:med chi-squared = 241.3114, df = 227, p-value = 0.2454

I appreciate very much for any explanation.

Have a great day,

Tuan

Comment: I suggest that you get the N33 and N31 objects and use `identical()` on them to see if they are really the same. Then when you find which one is different (or if they both are) you can dig into how they are different (class, decimal places etc).

Comment: `all.equal()` may give you additional insight into their differences

Comment: Thanks Elin and Apom. I tried both. the results are False for identical() and "Mean relative difference: 0.6797909" for all.equal(). Can you tell me how to intepret them and why they related to the difference in the results of simple regression for N33 and N31 as in my case? Many thanks.

Comment: A friend showed me that problems came from the data themselves. I checked and fixed. Thanks everyone.